# Make selection color in Firefox match the general Ubuntu/GNOME theme

Tags: gnome, firefox, themes, colors

The selection color (highlight when selecting text) in most apps is a pleasant shade of orange that matches the rest of the desktop. However, recently Firefox stopped following this convention and uses its own ugly shade of blue that I remember from Windows.

How do I make Firefox follow the OS here?

(Using Ubuntu 22.04 with GNOME 42.9 on Wayland.)